# Reverse the Reset and delete changes (--hard) operation VISUAL STUDIO 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, commit, reset

I'm using GIT with Visual Studio 2019, and I recently used the "Reset and delete changes (--hard)" option on a local commit I had done.

But this was an error, and the worst thing is I can't see the commit that was undone in the commit history, and I need to go back to the phase before this one, in other words, it would be possible to undo the operation that "Reset and delete changes ( --hard)" performed???
Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Use `git reflog` to see tbe id of the revision you want to go to. Then `git reset --hard that-id`

Comment: To help someone with `git reflog` often has this "then he walked into the sunset" vibe 8-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+reset+hard

Comment: @RomainValeri :-D it's becoming a mantra by now, man.